# Freeze row but only after you scroll down to it

Tags: excel

Hello Kind Ladies and Gentelmen. Anyone has a clue how to get this done. Let's say I want to freeze row 100, so initially it does not even show on your sheet. But I want to "freeze" it in a way that while I am above that row everything is normal, I can play around in row 1-99 as if NOTHING was frozen, until I scroll down to row 100, and until row 100 is at the top of my sheet ...and that's when I want that row frozen. So that I can go below row 100 but row 100 would stay visible at the top of my screen... BUT, again, if I go ABOVE row 100 I need it "unfrozen" ... any ideas?

I found a similar post titled "dynamically freezing panes in excel". But that is not exactlly it. There the guy needed the freeze to chnage when he "worked" in the sheet... meaning when he actually selected a cell. I need to freeze to react to simply scrolling and not even clicking a single cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamically freezing panes in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266012/dynamically-freezing-panes-in-excel)

Comment: Koby, thank you for your suggestion. I did check out that post you shared but it's not what I am looking for. But still, thank you for the effort.

Comment: I was going to suggest some kind of `Worksheet_Scroll` event, but it doesn't look like one exists in Excel... You'd have to create some kind of work around. I'm interested to see if anyone can find a solution to this.

Comment: Please check this Chip Pearson post on detecting scrolling using VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm